# Algorithm fast when just computing - slow when writing computed data to output buffer

Tags: c++, optimization

I have an algorithm that does some computations on elements of an array. I'd like to re-use the input-data buffer to write the results into it.
In terms of the data traversal pattern, it looks almost exactly like this (the only other thing happening in that for-loop are increments to some pointers and counting variables):

```
int *inputData = /*input data is here */;
for(int i=0;i<some_value;++i)
{
      int result = do_some_computations(*inputData);
      *inputData = result;
      ++inputData;
}
```

Now the interesting part: inputData contains about six million elements. If I comment out the write to the inputData array, so the algorithm looks basically like this:

```
int *inputData = /*input data is here */;
for(int i=0;i<some_value;++i)
{
      int result = do_some_computations(*inputData);
     // *inputData = result;
      ++inputData;
}
```

The algorithm, over a series of ~100 measurements, takes on average about 7 milliseconds. However, if I leave the write in, the algorithm takes about 55 milliseconds. Writing "*inputData = do_some_computations(*inputData);" instead of the way it is now makes no difference in performance. Using a separate outputBuffer makes no difference as well.

This is bad. The performance of this algorithm is absolutely critical to the requirements of the program. I was very happy with 7ms, however I am very unhappy with 55 ms.

Why does this single write-back cause such a large overhead, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you try using separate buffers for input and output? Did it also cause such slowdown?

Comment: It is possible that without the write-back, the optimiser removes the entire computation, since it doesn't have any observable effects. You could verify this by inspecting the assembly. You should also definitely try out @DariuszWawer's suggestion.

Comment: @Dariusz Wawer: Yes, exactly the same slowdown in fact. Still about 55ms.

Comment: @Angew no, not possible. The computations are pretty complicated and produce a lot of different numbers in the range [-2^16, + 2^16-1]

Comment: @TravisG: Have you actually verified that the code is not eliminated?

Comment: I'd also vote on optimizing out whole computations. Try to access random result element after the computation and check, if slowdown occurs.

Comment: @TravisG I'm just saying that regardless of the computations' complexity, if the result is just discarded in the end, the optimiser can notice and optimise them out.

Comment: @Angew mhm, that would be saddening. I'll check.

Comment: I doubt the compiler is optimizing it all away, as `*inputData = f(*inputData)` should also prevent optimizations, but makes no difference, so unless `do_some_computations` produces UB, I don't see how that can be the cause.

Comment: no, it does optimize it all away. by *inputData = f(*inputData) making no difference i meant that it was also 55ms slow.

Comment: @TravisG So how did you find out it optimized all away? Did you look at the assembly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is being optimised to nothing in the non-write back version. To show this, assuming a 5GHz single core CPU then:-

7ms = 35,000,000 cycles

6 million items = 35/6 = 5.8 cycles per item = not a lot of work being done

For the slow version:-

55ms = 275,000,000 cycles

6 million items = 275/6 = 45.8 cycles per item = far more work per item

If you want to verify this, look at the assembly output from the compiler.